# neo4j WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper not working

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j in embedded mode and want to access it on browser.I am using WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper for this.

```
WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper neoServerBootstrapper;


        try {
            GraphDatabaseAPI api = (GraphDatabaseAPI) graphDatabaseService;

            ServerConfigurator config = new ServerConfigurator(api);
            config.configuration()
                .addProperty(Configurator.WEBSERVER_ADDRESS_PROPERTY_KEY, "127.0.0.1");
            config.configuration()
                .addProperty(Configurator.WEBSERVER_PORT_PROPERTY_KEY, "7575");

            neoServerBootstrapper = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(api, config);
            neoServerBootstrapper.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
           //handle appropriately
        }
```

Server is up at 7575 but when i query then it is just loading,i am getting no data.

I am getting this script error

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.


...elector),!match||!match[1]&&context)return!context||context.jquery?(context||roo...
```

and also data is not coming from server,getting error 302 and 204.

Comment: The error is a javascript error, what browser are you using (and did you follow the steps for building static assets into your war file). 302 is not an error, where is the complete response?

Comment: @JohnMark13 i am using firefox and i didn't found anything about buildig static assets,i have setup just above configuration,do i need something for client side?

Comment: I guess you'd know if there was an issue with the assets by looking at your server logs (what server are you using?). Example fix for Tomcat - https://github.com/theon/neo4j-war-with-webadmin

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
  <classifier>static-web</classifier>
  <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

see: http://neo4j.com/docs/1.8.2/server-embedded.html

Comment: i have added this dependency already,  compile "org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:2.1.5"
  compile group: 'org.neo4j.app', name: 'neo4j-server', version: '2.1.5', classifier: 'static-web'

Comment: Do i need to enable_remote_shell and shell dependency also?

Comment: Not sure if it still works with 2.1.5 can you try with a 2.0 version first if the general setup works there?